# Cannot Export JS Module

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I've got a module called utilities in a `utilities.js` file. I am using it for some basic js functions and I want to hide the module from the global namespace. I understand that to do this I should create a module, export it, import it in the needed file, then invoke its functions. However, I cannot seem to properly export the module. I figure this is pretty simple but everything I have tried gives an error. Here is my code:

```
var utilities = (function(){
return {
    debounce: function(func, wait, immediate){
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    }
}
})();

export { utilities };
```

My error:

```
application.js:12560 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @DanielA.White Just updated my question with the error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
const utilities = function() {
  return {
    debounce: function(func, wait, immediate){
      var timeout;
        return function() {
          var context = this, args = arguments;
          var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
          };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
       };
     }
   }
 }

export default utilities;
```

or

```
function utilities() {
  return {
    debounce: function(func, wait, immediate){
      var timeout;
        return function() {
          var context = this, args = arguments;
          var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
          };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
       };
     }
   }
 }

 module.exports.utilities= utilities;
```

Comment: that exact code gives me `application.js:12541 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at application.js:12541`

Comment: Hm, just edited the answer, so give it a try, it works for me, both. @CannonMoyer

Comment: Still having the same problem. A quick search led me to CommonJS. Is this a requirement for using the exports keyword? I'm developing this code in a Rails application.

Comment: That is a change, look at this https://blog.arkency.com/2015/04/bring-commonjs-to-your-asset-pipeline/ ..... than my solution will work

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are exporting on server side. To use export keyword you need to transpile with babel. you can refer to this https://babeljs.io/setup#installation to learn how to set it up

for clientside you can set it up with webpack for example, it also needs babel transpile

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core
npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine in nodejs, if you are using browser script you need to have `<script type="module">` to use `export` keyword (es modules) or just transpile your code with babel